# assigning a struct instance to an inner nested struct in C

Tags: c, struct, nested

I am trying to organize the structure of a microcontroller in C using nested structs to group registers to a device port then all ports to a microcontroller instance.

```
typedef struct {
volatile unsigned char bit0:1, bit1:1, bit2:1, bit3:1, bit4:1, bit5:1, bit6:1, bit7:1;
}REG;

typedef struct {
REG addr;
REG ctl;
REG data;
}PORT;

typedef struct {
PORT porta;
PORT portb;
PORT portc;
}GPIO;

typedef struct {
GPIO gpio;
ADC adc;
UART uart;
}micro;

int main(void){
GPIO m_gpio;
micro m;
m.gpio = m_gpio;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: why use use `*`, it becomes pointer declaration. Are you aware this ?

Comment: Where/what is the exact problem?

Comment: my question is how i should instantiate struct micro in main and set the begining adress and how to acess the member structs to set individual register bits, say i want to set micro.gpio.porta.addr=0x01... and micro.gpio.porta.ctl.bit0=1;

Comment: here is a link to the main .h file in the project am writing https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/ez8_4k_XP.h?w=AAD-r1eWEQv_UVNyZVYnnStIwF2ZguJOmJUogdQRvhT7bA i just needed a demonstration of how nested structs work, with single structs for every register my code works just fine, i tested with UART communication, i have no idea how to do nested structs, i thought it could make the code well organised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the declarations you do will just give you local (stacked, typically) variables of the types mentioned.

That is not what you want when modelling registers, since the absolute address of each register is not on the stack at all, it's constant and well-known.

You're going to have to use pointers:

```
volatile GPIO * const gpio_a = (GPIO *) 0x008a4200;
```

That uses a totally made-up address, but you get the point.

The `volatile` is required so the compiler gets the hint that "yes, you really should do the read or write on each access, even if it seems pointless to you".

The `const` means "the value of this pointer cannot be changed", which is what you want for a pointer modelling a register.

Also, double (and triple) check that you get what you expect when using bitfields, they can be tricky. You're going to have to read the generated assembly.

Comment: this is a helpful answer, how about the micro type, how do i set its member device gpio to *gpio_a? just an example.

Comment: btw i am ok with the bitfeilds, as long as i use 'volatile unsigned char' they get assigned and read well.